# Ubuntu 16.04 & Canon mf620c & Wireless - printer ok; scanner not found

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, canon, scanner

I have a Canon MF628Cw/MF624Cw (mf620c class driver) printer/scanner. I've installed the printer drivers no problem. The scanner drivers will not work.

I've tried VueScan, and from the logs there, it would seem that the scanner is not responding when VueScan tries to talk to it (according to VueScan help).

Have reinstalled Canon drivers from US, UK and Asia sites, all with the same result.

Thoughts?

Comment: It's the same with Samsung multifunction devices. Printing install is automatic, but scanner install is suffering! How did you install printer drivers? by apt?

Comment: UK drivers are .deb files, so easy.

Comment: I suspect the drivers you installed just enabled printing function, putting scanning function outside. I suggest you to search for complete drivers (printer and scanner). Look at [this page](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/08/14/canon-printer-driver-scangear-mp-ubuntu-16-04/)

Comment: Thanks, but the MF series is not part of this solution.  Hence, my continued search for a solution.